# What is the best way of accessing json file using local or global variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cordova, object

I am code for Cordova javascript currently, I am using JSON array object to store examples, questions, answer and more details, approximately the object size is 1MB, and store the objects into a global variable and access it whenever need it like below.

```
var _quiz=
[{
    v1:1
    ,code:"q1"
    ,type:"x1"
    ,question:"This is the question"
    ,answer:1
    ,options:"Ans1!###Ans2!###Ans3###Ans4"
},
{
    v1:1
    ,type:"x2"
    ,certificate:"bronz"
    ,question:"This is the question"
    ,answer:3
    ,options:"Ans1!###Ans2!###Ans3###Ans4"
}
...
...
];


//Need to call many times
function processQuestion()
{
    _quiz
    ...
    ...
}
```

But I think this occupies more space in memory and may cause to crash the application. So I think we can store and return the JSON object from the function whenever needs, so it will not take too much memory and objects store as a local variable like the below example. Please suggest the best method.

```
function get_object()
{
    var obj=
    [{
        v1:1
        ,code:"q1"
        ,type:"x1"
        ,question:"This is the question"
        ,answer:1
        ,options:"Ans1!###Ans2!###Ans3###Ans4"
    },
    {
        v1:1
        ,type:"x2"
        ,certificate:"bronz"
        ,question:"This is the question"
        ,answer:3
        ,options:"Ans1!###Ans2!###Ans3###Ans4"
    }
    ...
    ...
    ];

    return obj;
}


//Need to call many times
function processQuestion()
{
    var ques=get_object();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Bu using the second way like var ques=get_object() you are creating more variables with that value and using more space and memory

Comment: @HitechHitesh but it will remove from the memory after the function closed,

Comment: var keywords declares things globally use let

Comment: Is this all synchronous code? i.e. will `processQuestion()` be called multiple times in sequence or in parallel? Is storing data on the global object the only option?

Comment: @Kai I will call the function much time, for example, every quiz have 10 to 30 questions with 20seconds gap.

Comment: @HitechHitesh If I use let, is the second method is correct?

Comment: Yes in the second method and one more thing you can do is remove the var declaration and directly return the object from the get_object() function so there also declaration would be there like return {object} .

Answer (score 0):

Use let in the second method and one more thing you can do is remove the var declaration and directly return the object from the get_object() function so there also declaration would be there like return {object} .